# Intel HD audio codec power management

Tags: 11.10, sound, power-management, hda-intel

Is it possible to enable power management for intel-hda sound card audio codec ? Power management for the card itself works fine, but audio codec module (/sys/module/snd_hda_codec) doesn't seem to expose any parameters for power management, although **powertop** utility suggests to enable it and shows its power usage, which is 100%, always on top.

Answer (score 3):

To set your time-out 10 seconds (Adjust as you like):

```
echo 10 > /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save
```

You can verify if powersave is on by

```
cat /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save_controller
```

Powertop will always show 100% cpu on those though, it's a known error.