# Clicking sound when playing audio

Tags: 14.04, drivers, sound, macbook, soundcard

Before flagging this question as duplicate, this is not a random or periodic clicking sound. It only happens once a sound is played on the speakers for the "first time".

"First time" being after a few seconds of silence. The audio driver could be asleep, and once a sound is reproduced it wakes up triggering a "click".

Is there any way to remove this anoying sound?

```
Ubuntu 14,04
NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 High Definition Audio (rev b1)
```

Comment: Without detailed information I can only say that this is usually a power management issue of the audio codec and give you this example http://askubuntu.com/q/97868/40581

Comment: Yes, it's power related. Thanks for pointing that out. I noticed that it only happens when the power cable is removed, to save power Ubuntu puts the driver to sleep while on battery. Now that is a reasonable price to pay to lower the energy consumption. And I can always reattach the cable to get rid of the "clicks".

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, that is the sound of your speakers "activating". It happens on all of my computers, *heck*, it happens on ALL computers.

So, you can't really remove that sound, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Older Ubuntu 11.04 and Elementary OS don't have this clicking sound while running on the same machine. This is not a normal behavior even if you are accustomed to it.

Comment: @GabrielMeono Are you sure it's the software?  Not your hardware?   I've heard it on cheap and old computers, but never when the speakers were replaced with Harman-Kardons...

Comment: As @LiveWireBT mentioned this is power related, and depends on the OS. I commented about this below my question.